# Chrome Rendering Shown content as missing

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-chrome

This is a pretty annoying bug that involves hiding and showing content for a mobile menu. I've tried many different approaches, with hiding the content, or alternately throwing the content to left: 400%, but regardless of what I try so often when I reload the page, once the menu icon is clicked, the menu "appears" according to chrome (all its classes are set correctly) but it simply isn't displaying. It only happens maybe 1 out of 4 times [here.](http://dev.askmova.org/search.html?search=tinn)

You'll have to reload the page and tap on the green filter each time. You can see how the menu is supposed to work, but it vanishes on occasion. This bug is only happening on chrome. It works fine on ie, ff and safari. This is a bootstrap site, so to see the mobile menu, shrink your browser down to < 767px.

HTML:

```
    <div class="row row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-left">
      <a id="filter-toggle" href="#" class="pull-left visible-xs">
        <img src="/assets/custom/images/filter-icon.png"/>
      </a>

      <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 sidebar-offcanvas" id="sidebar" ng-controller="resourceCategoryCtrl">
        <a id="menu-toggle" href="#" class="pull-right visible-xs hidden-xs">
          <img src="/assets/custom/images/filter-icon.png"/>
        </a> 

        <h2 class="filter-heading">Categories</h2>

        <div class="list-group">
          <span data-toggle="offcanvas" class="visible-xs ng-cloak menu-shift"><a href="#" class="list-group-item resource-category rc-font" data-category-id="{{category.id}}" ng-repeat="category in categories" ng-click="toggleCategory()">{{category.title}}</a></span>

          <a href="#" class="list-group-item resource-category rc-font hidden-xs ng-cloak" data-category-id="{{category.id}}" ng-repeat="category in categories" ng-click="toggleCategory()">{{category.title}}</a>
        </div>
      </div><!--/.sidebar-offcanvas-->

      <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-7 col-md-offset-1" id="article" ng-controller="resourceCtrl">
        <h2 class="category-header font-category ng-cloak">{{category.title}}</h2>
        <div ng-show="resourceLoading" class="loading-gif">
          <div class="loading"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="resource-p" ng-show="!resourceLoading" ng-repeat="resource in resources">
          <resource></resource>
        </div>
        <p ng-show="noResults" class="no-results ng-cloak">No results found.</p>

        <div class="text-center" ng-show="totalItems > itemsPerPage && !resourceLoading">
          <pagination max-size="maxSize" num-pages="numPages" total-items="totalItems" items-per-page="itemsPerPage" ng-model="currentPage" ng-change="pageChanged()" boundary-links="false" rotate="true"></pagination>
        </div>
    </div><!-- .row --> 

  </div><!-- .container --> 
  <div class="push"></div>
</section>

<footer class="footer bg-dark">
     <div class="text-center">
      <a href="tos.html" class="tos-title">Terms of Service</a>
    </div>
</footer>
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.filter-toggle').on('click', function () {
    $('.row-offcanvas').toggleClass('active');
    $('.sidebar-offcanvas').toggleClass('extend');
    $('#article').toggleClass('hide');
    $('footer').toggleClass('hide');
    $('#menu-toggle').toggleClass('hidden-xs');
    $('#filter-toggle').toggleClass('hidden-xs');

  });
  $('#menu-toggle').on('click', function () {
    $('.sidebar-offcanvas').toggleClass('extend');
    $('.row-offcanvas').toggleClass('active');
    $('#menu-toggle').toggleClass('hidden-xs');
    $('#filter-toggle').toggleClass('hidden-xs');
    $('#article').toggleClass('hide');
    $('footer').toggleClass('hide');
  });
  $('.menu-shift').on('click', function () {
    $('.sidebar-offcanvas').toggleClass('extend');
    $('.row-offcanvas').toggleClass('active');
    $('#menu-toggle').toggleClass('hidden-xs');
    $('#filter-toggle').toggleClass('hidden-xs');
    $('#article').toggleClass('hide');
    $('footer').toggleClass('hide');
  });
});
```

CSS:

```
  .extend {
    width: 100%;
  }

  .row-offcanvas-left {
    left: 0;
  }

 .row-offcanvas-left.active {
   left: 50%;
 }
```

Comment: Could you provide the CSS for the classes that are being toggled in the above JS?

Comment: Are you trying to hide/show content based on screen size?

Comment: CSS provided. Basically Im hiding the content on the right hand side of the menu. Hiding/Showing the filter icons on either side of the menu, and also hiding the footer. While Im swinging the menu out to 50% and enlarging the menu itself to be width 100%. This is all happening in the mobile menu only.